# Create Google App Scripts add-on that adds a BottomBar

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to create an add on that adds a bottom-bar to Google Drive/Sheets?

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui I can only see a sideBar and a modal. Looks like bottomBar is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to create a sticky bottom bar. You can create a [modal/modeless dialog/sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) or a non-interactive [toast](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg-title-timeoutseconds) message at the bottom right.